# android - detect when the app is on the foreground through a library

Tags: android, android-library

Is there a decent way to detect through a android shared library when the app that references the library has gone into the background/foreground? The library has no access to any activities whatsoever, asides from Context.

i.e Can the library register a broadcast receiver to receive such events?

Comment: How about this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15487754/androidhow-to-check-if-application-is-running-in-background-2
You'll need the library do depend on Android SDK though.

Comment: the library is fine to depend on the SDK, however I'm not sure I want to do this on demand. Ideally, once the library is initialised, I would like to be able to handle the events automatically (i.e has the app resumed again). I'm not sure if this is possible hence the question here :-)

Comment: The common way would be to have some code in `Activity#onPause` and `Activity#onResume` notify the library code of application state changes. If you create an abstract `Activity` subclass that does just that as a part of your library and make all other activities extend it, you'll save yourself a code duplication.

Comment: Yes, some sort of callback that the library would handle I guess. I guess I was asking mostly because the library is meant for other developers and I would want to minimise the code they need to write for my library to work. Thanks for the confirmation.